# Calling launch without paranthesis in kotlin coroutines

Tags: kotlin-coroutines

I understand that `launch` is an extension function on CoroutineScope. But then I see it being used like this:

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.*

fun main() {
    GlobalScope.launch { // launch a new coroutine in background and continue
        delay(1000L) // non-blocking delay for 1 second (default time unit is ms)
        println("World!") // print after delay
    }
    println("Hello,") // main thread continues while coroutine is delayed
    Thread.sleep(2000L) // block main thread for 2 seconds to keep JVM alive
}
```

My understaning is that in kotlin one can define an infix function and then call it without any paranthesis. But from the documenation, I don't think `launch` is an infix function (in fact it has more than one parameter, so it can not be infix). It is also not a keyword in language. Then how is it called without any paranthesis?

Answer (score 1):

The first two parameters are default parameters and the third one is High order function. When the last parameter is High order function then you can move Lamba out of parenthesis.

Suppose you have fun:

```
fun post(s:String="default", block:()->Unit){}
```

You call it in these ways:

```
 post("1",{

  })
```

You will get a suggestion *Lamda should be moved out of parentheses*

After moving out of parentheses:

```
 post("1"){

  }
```

Now you can remove the first parameter since it is default parameter

```
  post {
   
  }
```

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html